# $G$ $p$-group, $G^{ab}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ implies $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The following result seems to be a classical one in group theory:

let $G$ be a finite $p$-group such that $G/[G,G]\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$

Could anyone provide me with a reference ? or even better, a proof of this fact (not using (co)homology).

Thanks in advance !

Greg

Comment: A group of order $p^n$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for all $k \le n$. So if $n \ge 2$, then there is a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p^{n-2}$. Then $|G/N| = p^2$, so $G/N$ is abelian and $[G,G] \le N$. So if $|G/[G,G]|=p$, then $|G|=p$.